# Which standard/format does Locale class in Java return?

Tags: java, iso

If you have the following code snippet and you set the format in the regional settings you sometimes get two letters before the underscore and sometimes you get three letters before the underscore. In ISO 639-1 you only have two letters so it can't be that one?

```
System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Java 7 docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html):

1. **language** - ISO 639 alpha-2 or alpha-3 language code, or registered language subtags up to 8 alpha letters
2. **script** - ISO 15924 alpha-4 script code
3. **country (region)** ISO 3166 alpha-2 country code or UN M.49 numeric-3 area code.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's not an ISO standard, but a concatenation of the following fields:

> language + "*" + country + "*" + (variant + "_#" | "#") + script + "-" + extensions

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#toString%28%29), this can return the following:

> Language is always lower case, country is always upper case, script is
>   always title case, and extensions are always lower case. Extensions
>   and private use subtags will be in canonical order as explained in
>   toLanguageTag(). When the locale has neither script nor extensions,
>   the result is the same as in Java 6 and prior.
>
> If both the language and country fields are missing, this function
>   will return the empty string, even if the variant, script, or
>   extensions field is present (you can't have a locale with just a
>   variant, the variant must accompany a well-formed language or country
>   code).
>
> If script or extensions are present and variant is missing, no
>   underscore is added before the "#".
>
> This behavior is designed to support debugging and to be compatible
>   with previous uses of toString that expected language, country, and
>   variant fields only. To represent a Locale as a String for interchange
>   purposes, use toLanguageTag().
>
> Examples:
>
> en de_DE
>   _GB en_US_WIN de__POSIX zh_CN_#Hans zh_TW_#Hant-x-java th_TH_TH_#u-nu-thai

Comment: Why does it for some languages in the regional settings return xxx_XX? I mean what kind of standard does the regional settings in control panel follow? Or is it some kind of convertion in Java? I don't get how it return both 2 and 3 letters before the underscore.

Comment: Can you tell which languages return the xxx_XX?

Comment: Btw, the documentation says: ISO 639 alpha-2 or alpha-3 language code, or registered language subtags up to 8 alpha letters (for future enhancements). So it seems alpha-3 is supported too.

Comment: Why doesn't it return ISO 639-3 all the time? Then it would have been consistent with three letters?

Comment: Again, according to the docs: When a language has both an alpha-2 code and an alpha-3 code, the alpha-2 code must be used. So I guess it doesn't have a alpha-2 code? According to Wikipedia, this seems to be true: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sami_languages